# How do I change my Wordpress search to be an OR search instead of an AND search?

Tags: wordpress

Currently my Wordpress site does an AND search. That means if the URI is /?s=blue+green, it will only return posts which contain both blue AND green.

I'd like to change this so it will return any posts which contain blue OR green.

Do any of you know what code I need to change to do this?

I'm using Wordpress 4.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If life was simple, we'd be out of a job :)

- Step 1. Take a look at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page) about how to create a
  custom search page.
- Step 2.Then take a look at the [Widgets_API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API).
- Step 3. Combine the 2 to create your own search widget, then use that
  instead of the supplied one.

OR

refer to the [get_search_form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form) reference, and write your won search function in your themes' functions.php.